# Azalea dieback issue

Tags: diagnosis, azaleas

I’m living in Melbourne
, Australia and have recently noticed over the last month or so a large area of dieback shrivelled brown leaves on a clients Azaleas plants.
A pH test has a returned a neutral(7) pH. Other azaleas in the hedge appear to be healthy. I’ve applied some soil acidifier to make the pH slightly acidic. It’s had an application of azalea acidic fertiliser within the last month. I was wondering if anyone has seen this sort of dieback before, I can’t see many signs of pests there is a small degree of azalea lace bug on some nearby plants but nothing too serious.
Any help appreciated,

Cheers.

Photos below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Has the paving been recently repaired?

Comment: hmm, I don't think so. But your question made me wonder whether weeds in the pavement cracks had been sprayed leading to potential poisoning.